# React-native Android app keeps rejecting because of new policies by google play console: sensitive informations

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-console

[image]

The app keeps rejecting because of new sensitive policies. In the manifest. I have included these three permissions:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />`.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS" />`.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />`

**Any idea how to approve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use Google SMS API instead of current react-native basic implementation.
https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add a privacy policy in the play store

Comment: Already added, I think this is coming from the code level.

Comment: Using react-native package for achieving this OTP scenario.

Comment: I posted an answer for my own question